# Exposing JS constructor for NPM front end library?

Tags: javascript, npm, frontend

I have published my first package on NPM and have run into some issues which I have been ripping my hair out over. I feel like the issue may be something simple I am missing but I need to ask for my own sanity.

I published the package already, but the issue I have run into is it seems like I am having some scope problems when bundling the files using browserify. I have my micro-lib wrapped in an IIFE and am trying to module.export the constructor which is returned at the bottom of the IIFE, it looks something like this:

```
var Package = (function() {

    /* Constructor */
    function Package(foo, bar) {
       this.foo = foo;
       this.bar = bar;
    }

     // Bunch of private methods (don't HAVE to be private)

    // API methods I want user to be able to access from chrome console

    Package.prototype.$method = function() {
        return this.foo;
    };

    return Package;
})();

// Expose constructor?
module.exports = Package;
```

The goal is to allow the user to require my package

```
var package = require('package-name');
var P = new package(foo, bar);
```

^^ The above works so far if I throw in a console.log(P); It will log to the console, but when I want the package consumer to use the prototype from the console to say log out some of the config settings just for reference by doing:

```
P.$config();
```

It doesn't work, even though the user has successful instantiated the object from the package, but it logs undefined when trying to "re-access" the variable in the console. It seems that when bundling the file that it is wrapped in an IIFE from browserify and is no longer public to be accessible from the chrome console... What am I doing wrong here? I am sure it's quite a few things but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I've tried bundling browserify with --standalone (-s) to expose the module.exports package variable but it's not working. Can anyone take a minute or two to explain the workflow for publishing an npm (front end) package? Do I need to remove the IIFE around my package and just have the constructor out in the open?

Thanks in advance guys I appreciate it.

Comment: Show me the implementation of that `$config` method. You say it doesn't work but we can't tell as we don't know how you implemented one.

Comment: Ah sorry I mentioned it was a prototype method that just returned some options. The way I am using it would be the config method would just return the options passed into the constructor and all it does is log it out. As an example pretend the constructor took a name parameter, all the $config method would do is return this.name. Package.prototype.$config = function() {
   return this.name;
};

Comment: Is this package public? Could you tell me its name so I could install for testing?

Comment: I ommited going into that package. Tested that script in question instead. Using `P.$method()` works well for me. I simply made a browserify script out of that above module and it worked fine.

Comment: Grab a Gist: https://gist.github.com/Nonemoticoner/55a45b35665900f247cbd9dfc927c5dd

Comment: Did it work? I'll post an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you wrote is fine. You just have to deal with one properly. Write such *script.js* to get global variable `h` for further use:

```
h = require('./index.js');   // file with your module
```

Then, use browserify:

```
browserify script.js > lel.js
```

Then you may use it within your application like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="lel.js"></script>
    <script>
        var lel = new h(123, 456);

        console.log(lel.$method()); // 123
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't tell if this is as good practice as possible but it work perfectly for me.